# View song's title on terminal

Tags: terminal, vlc

How to view currently playing song's title on terminal using `vlc` media player?

Answer (score 3):

If you run VLC using it's remote control facility `vlc -I rc` you can interact with a running `vlc` session. There's a good tutorial on it over here, titled:

[Controlling VLC via RC (“Remote Control”) interface using a UNIX domain socket (and no programming)](http://n0tablog.wordpress.com/2009/02/09/controlling-vlc-via-rc-remote-control-interface-using-a-unix-domain-socket-and-no-programming/).

In a nutshell you launch `vlc` like so:

```
$ vlc -I rc /home/saml/Desktop/desktop/mp3/stevesongs/marvelous_day/fast_monkey.mp3
VLC media player 1.1.12 The Luggage (revision exported)
Blocked: call to unsetenv("DBUS_ACTIVATION_ADDRESS")
Blocked: call to unsetenv("DBUS_ACTIVATION_BUS_TYPE")
[0x700650] [rc] lua interface: Listening on host "*console".
VLC media player 1.1.12 The Luggage
Remote control interface initialized. Type `help' for help.
>
```

**NOTE:** You can also run it using a playlist, I'm just showing a single MP3 for this example.

Now you're at a vlc prompt where you can interact with vlc and find out things such as info about the playlist and what's currently playing:

*status*

```
> status
( new input: file:///home/saml/Desktop/desktop/mp3/stevesongs/marvelous_day/fast_monkey.mp3 )
( audio volume: 256 )
( state playing )
>
```

*playlist*

```
> playlist
+----[ Playlist - Undefined ]
| 2 - Playlist
|   4 - Fast Monkey (00:03:34) [played 1 time]
| 3 - Media Library
+----[ End of playlist ]
>
```

#### Fake TTY

If you don't want to have to interact with the `vlc` prompt you can get `vlc` to run with a fake TTY device so that you can interact with it through a socket.

[image: ss of dialog #1]

[image: ss of dialog #2]

**NOTE:** The screenshots are from a OSX laptop. If you're doing this on Linux you'll need to follow the steps on the videolan website to enable RC & Fake TTY. The steps are outlined on this guide, titled: [How to use VLC for transcription in linux](http://wiki.videolan.org/How_to_use_VLC_for_transcription_in_linux).

*Hint the dialog above is under the pull down in the main VLC window, Tools -> Preferences, on Linux.*

Once `vlc` is setup with the fake TTY you can direct commands to it through the cli through netcat (`nc`):

```
$ echo -n "pause"    | nc -U /Users/vlc.sock
$ echo -n "playlist" | nc -U /Users/vlc.sock
```

Comment: Interesting info, but I still cannot get the track titles from [the Radio Swiss Jazz stream](http://hamwaves.com/streams/doc/ch.radio_swiss_jazz.aac+.96k.m3u) that nonetheless appear in the title bar of `vlc` with a GUI.

Answer (score -1):

The command

ffprobe "http://stream.srg-ssr.ch/m/rsj/aacp_96"

tells you what's playing now on Radio Swiss Jazz. Look for "StreamTitle" in its output.